# Run a single test in Flash Builder?

Tags: tdd, flash-builder, flexunit

I have been using Flash Builder to build my flex software and I am a TDD guy.  I find it irritating that I have to run ALL my tests in order to run any tests.  It causes friction in my TDD workflow.  I really want to write a test, and run that test in isolation.  I do this in .Net all the time (with TD.NET plugin), but I can't find a way to do it in Flash Builder.  Is there a way?

I just downloaded the trial InteliJ IDEA and it support the behavior I want.  Can I do this in Flash Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right-click on the actual test method in the Package Explorer and select the "Execute FlexUnit Tests" option it will only execute that specific test.

Comment: Cool!  For bonus points, is there any way to do it from the editor?  A hot key, preferably, so I don't even need to hit my mouse?

Comment: Select the method in the text editor and press Alt + Shift + E, F.